# How do you decode utf8-literals like "\xc3\xa6" in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, decode

I am fetching a list of WiFi SSID's from a Bluetooth characteristic. Each SSID is represented as a string, some have these UTF8-Literals like "\xc3\xa6".

I have tried multiple ways to decode this like

```
let s = "\\xc3\\xa6"
let dec = s.utf8
```

From this I expect

```
print(dec)
> æ
```

etc. but it doesn't work, it just results in

```
print(dec)
> \xc3\xa6
```

How do I decode UTF-8 literals in Strings in Swift 5?

Comment: Well there's no magic. You'll just have to parse the text, convert to `[UInt8]`, then to `Data`, then you can put it in the `String.init(bytes:encoding:)` initialiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to parse the string, convert each hex string to a `UInt8`, and then decode that with `String.init(byte:encoding:)`:

```
let s = "\\xc3\\xa6"
let bytes = s
    .components(separatedBy: "\\x")
    // components(separatedBy:) would produce an empty string as the first element
    // because the string starts with "\x". We drop this
    .dropFirst() 
    .compactMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
if let decoded = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(decoded)
} else {
    print("The UTF8 sequence was invalid!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this returns me the correct character 'æ'.

But how about if the string is like this:

>let s = "WiFiName\\xc3\\xa6Test"

Then it doesn't return me anything as the String literal isn't the last part of the string?

Comment: I accepted the answer, as it answers my original question. I should however probably have asked about the string in a real life context where the String literal is just a part of a regular string.

As I am unsure how this method would fare if the character is a part of a regular sentence. As this only works when the character is separated from the rest of the sentence.

I.e. it wouldn't work if the string was:

let s = "\\xc3\\xa6Test"

Comment: @YoungChul A simple way is to write a regex to find that particular portion. Using something like `(\\x[\da-f]{2})+`. You can post a new question if you are having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a whole string, we can use the new Regex Builder in Swift 5.7, and build off [Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70034404/10871073). We might do something like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import RegexBuilder

extension String {
  
  public func decodingUTF8Characters() throws -> String {
    let regex = Regex {
      #"\x"#
      Capture {
        Repeat(count: 2) {
          .hexDigit
        }
      }
    }
    
    return try self.replacing(regex) { match in
     let hexString = String(match.output.1)
      
      guard let byte = UInt8(hexString, radix: 16),
            let decodedString = String(bytes: [byte], encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw UTF8DecodingError(string: hexString)
      }
      
      return decodedString
    }
  }
  
  struct UTF8DecodingError: LocalizedError {
    let string: String
    var errorDescription: String? {
      "Couldn't decode '\(string)' as UTF8 string"
    }
  }
}
```