# Decoding strings including utf8-literals like '\xc3\xa6' in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, decode, swift5

Follow up question to my former [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034125/how-do-you-decode-utf8-literals-like-xc3-xa6-in-swift-5) about UTF-8 literals:

It was established that you can decode UTF-8 literals from string like this that exclusively includes UTF-8 literals:

```
let s = "\\xc3\\xa6"
let bytes = s
    .components(separatedBy: "\\x")
    // components(separatedBy:) would produce an empty string as the first element
    // because the string starts with "\x". We drop this
    .dropFirst() 
    .compactMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
if let decoded = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(decoded)
} else {
    print("The UTF8 sequence was invalid!")
}
```

However this only works if the string only contains UTF-8 literals. As I am fetching a Wi-Fi list of names that has these UTF-8 literals within, how do I go about decoding the entire string?

Example:

```
let s = "This is a WiFi Name \\xc3\\xa6 including UTF-8 literals \\xc3\\xb8"
```

With the expected result:

```
print(s)
> This is a WiFi Name æ including UTF-8 literals ø
```

In Python there is a simple solution to this:

```
contents = source_file.read()
uni = contents.decode('unicode-escape')
enc = uni.encode('latin1')
dec = enc.decode('utf-8')
```

Is there a similar way to decode these strings in Swift 5?

Comment: how are you delimiting the hex literals from the text?  Will there always be a space following them?

Comment: @flanker Unfortunately, they are just inside the text. With no space or anything in between or after.

So a common string could be

 "Netv\\xc3\\xa6rk 5GHz" for "Netværk 5GHz"

Comment: loop through, use a regex to find the range of the next literal, extract the range and decode it, then replace that range with the decoded version?  If no one comes up with a working solution I'll have a crack later.

Comment: @flanker, thanks I was hoping there was a simpler Swift option as in the Python example below. As I am not very strong in Regex. However I would definitely appreciate your effort if no one has an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with add the decoding code into a String extension as a computed property (or create a function)

```
extension String {
    var decodeUTF8: String {
        let bytes = self.components(separatedBy: "\\x")
            .dropFirst()
            .compactMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
        return String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8) ?? self
    }
}
```

Then use a regular expression and match using a while loop to replace all matching values

```
while let range = string.range(of: #"(\\x[a-f0-9]{2}){2}"#, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) {
    string.replaceSubrange(range, with: String(string[range]).decodeUTF8)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no native Swift solution to this.  To make it look as compact as the Python version at the call site you can build an extension on `String` to hide the complexity

```
extension String {
   func replacingUtf8Literals() -> Self {

      let regex = #"(\\x[a-zAZ0-9]{2})+"#
      
      var str = self
      
      while let range = str.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) {
         let literalbytes = str[range]
            .components(separatedBy: "\\x")
            .dropFirst()
            .compactMap{UInt8($0, radix: 16)}
         guard let actuals = String(bytes: literalbytes, encoding: .utf8) else {
            fatalError("Regex error")
         }
         str.replaceSubrange(range, with: actuals)
      }
      return str
   }
}
```

This lets you call

```
print(s.replacingUtf8Literals()). 

//prints: This is a WiFi Name æ including UTF-8 literals ø
```

For convenience I'm trapping a failed conversion with `fatalError`.  You may want to handle this in a better way in production code (although, unless the regex is wrong it should never occur!).  There needs to be some form of break or error thrown here else you have an infinite loop.

Comment: If you remove 2 \\ from your regex and "separatedBy" so that its

let regex = #"(?:\\x[a-zAZ0-9]{2})+"# and separatedBy: "\\x"

This works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was careless of me.  Where I was playing with the regex I escaped the already escaped sring, and ended up with double escaping ...  and then just copied it over!  I've edited the answer.